# Variety but not group automorphism of $GL(n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Are there some variety automorphisms of the affine variety $GL(n)$ that are not group automorphisms? (no restiction on the field of definition)

Comment: Translation by a fixed element is a variety automorphism and not a group automorphism unless you chose the identity element. The question gets ore interesting when you require that the automorphism preserves the identity element.

Answer (score 3):

Left (or right) multiplication by an invertible matrix is an automorphism which does not fix the unit, hence is not a group automorphism. The transposition is another example. In fact
$$
\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{GL}_n) \supset 
\left(\frac{\mathrm{GL}_n \times \mathrm{GL}_n}{\mathrm{G}_{\mathrm{m}}}\right) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2,
$$
while group automorphisms is the group $\mathrm{PGL}_n$ embedded diagonally.

Comment: Thank you, is $\Bbb{Z}/2$ for the inverse, and $GL_n\times GL_n$ for the left and right multiplication ?

Comment: In fact, I was too hasty when claiming the equality; but there is definitely an embedding. And although I meant the transpostion for $\mathbb{Z}/2$, you can also consider the inversion.